# Mobile Chat doesn't load on iOS 5.0.1

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

After updating my iPad to iOS 5.0.1, when I attempt to load chat it hangs at the "just a second..." screen. Non-mobile appears to be fine on it.

Comment: Reproduced on 4th generation iPod touch. The debug console shows that something is trying to execute an undefined function.

Comment: confirmed, Ben will have a look in a few hours

Comment: Not working on iOS 5.0.1 either

Comment: @SimonSheehan isn't that what the OP says?

Comment: mine doesn't work either, but it's only iOS 5.0.1

Comment: @Jon meant to say 5.0.0. Also having issues pre-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wasn't an iOS issue; just a plain JavaScript bug that caused the mobile version to fail. Fixed now; thanks and sorry about that.